# Unable to replace the file variable with passed json variables

Tags: python

I am trying to generate dag files using python code below.
The code below takes  two parameters -

1. bunch of looped json file input
2. Template which provides the line which the variables has to be applied

I can successfully create output files but the variables which is replicated from the template file did not change. When the file gets created I want the json variables to be passed to the new file created dynamically.

json file:

```json
{
    "DagId": "dag_file_xyz",
    "Schedule": "'@daily'",
    "Processed_file_name":"xyz1",
    "Source_object_name":"'xyz2,}
```

Template:

```py
  processed_file = xyzOperator(
        task_id=processed_file_name,
        source_bucket=bucket_path,
        destination_bucket=destination_bucket,
        source_object=source_object_name,
        destination_object=destination_object_name,
        delimiter='.csv',
        move_object=False
```

Generate file code

```py
import json
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import ctypes

config_filepath = ('C:\\xyz\\')
dag_template_filename = 'C:\\dagfile\\xyztest.py'

for filename in os.listdir(config_filepath):
    print(filename)
    f = open(config_filepath + filename)
    print(f)
    config = json.load(f)

    new_filename = 'dags/' + config['DagId'] + '.py'
    print(new_filename)
    shutil.copyfile(dag_template_filename, new_filename)

    for line in fileinput.input(new_filename, inplace=True):
        print(line)
        line.replace("dag_id", "'" + config['DagId'] + "'"))
        line.replace("scheduletoreplace", config['Schedule'])
        line.replace("processed_file_name", config['Processed_file_name'])
        line.replace("source_object_name", config['Source_object_name'])
        line.replace("destination_object_name", config['Destination_object_name'])
        print(line, end="")
```

Comment: You need to read the lines of file in a variable, make changes to the lines and then write them back to a new file.
'line.replace' will not replace the line in the actual file

Comment: Note that `line.replace(old, new)` **does not** change `line`; it calculates a new `line` value, but if you don't store that new value somewhere it just gets thrown away.

Comment: ...also, programatically generating source code is a practice best left for people expert enough to know (1) what the security and correctness risks incurred are and how to avoid them; and (2) how to avoid needing to do it in the first place.